# Is it possible to restore files accidentally removed after `git add`?

Tags: git

After adding all my changes using `git add --all`, I accidentally deleted files of more than one depth with `mv -f app/* members && rm -rf app` (instead of using `cp -rf app members`). When I run `git status`, it tells me:

```
deleted:    app/more/than/one/depth/file.php
...
```

Is it possible to get those files back from the Git cache?

Comment: You can just commit the change as it is (`git commit`), and then check out the resulting tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trivially, yes.

```
git checkout -- app
```

...will restore everything in the tree.